# Node app usage tracking, how should I go about this?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm building an app that allows for watching multiple gaming streams at the same time. I want the client to tell the node server when it starts watching a stream and when the client stops watching that stream. That way, I can keep track of how long a user has watched a specific stream and add that stream to their viewing history as well.

My question is: how would I go about doing this? I was thinking of setting up keep-alive pings and once I find that the last one was a reasonable amount of time since the previous, the client is assumed to have stopped watching a stream. This seems like a bit of a hassle to set up properly. I want to know if there's a library that would allow me to do that easily. I've looked at socket.io, but I don't really understand the purpose of it or if it would apply to my situation.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use socket.io to do this. There is built-in heartbeat funcionality in socket.io. What you need to do is handling `disconnected` event. More info at: https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-spec

**Update:**

On your client:

```
socket.emit('startWatch', { streamid: 'stream1' });
....
socket.emit('stopWatch', {});
```

On your server:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  // listen to startWatch event
  socket.on('startWatch', function (msg) {
     // handle startWatch here
  });

  //listen to stopWatch event
  var stopWatchHandler = function () {... }
  socket.on('stopWatch", stopWatchHandler);
  socket.on('disconnected", stopWatchHandler);
});
```

Comment: Since this is for multiple streams on one client, I assume there's a way to set custom events? When they start a stream I'd tell the server via a "<user> started <stream>" kind of event, then either on manual close or disconnect I can do "<user> stopped <stream>"?

Comment: @MaxGhost Yes. On your client:

Comment: Very nice. Thanks for the edit, looks like that's the route I'll take.

Answer (score 1):

Socket.io (or the like) is what you want.

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log('user connected');
  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });
});
```

Comment: What are "the like", so I can explore my options?

Comment: Here are some: https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client, https://github.com/substack/shoe, https://github.com/LearnBoost/engine.io

They handle things from the multiple web socket protocols, to fallbacks such as XHR, to message protocols on top.